# Post array text input value to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to retrieve the input value which is an array using AJAX.

```
<td>
 <label for=""><?php _e( 'State' ); ?></label>
 <input type="text" name="state_to[<?php echo $country_id ?>][]" class=" state_selection" placeholder="State name">
</td>

$('.location-wrapper').on('change', '.state_selection', function() {

        var country = $('#country_selection').val();
var self = $(this),
    data = {
        //state_id : self.find(':selected').val(),
        state_id : $('input[name="state_to[country][]"]').val(),
        country_id: $('#country_selection').val(),
        action    : 'select_zip_by_state_country'       
    };

    });
```

I am able to retrieve correct value fpr country but not for state. Please can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```
$('.location-wrapper').on('change', '.state_selection', function() {
  var country = $('#country_selection').val();
  var self = $(this),
  data = {
    //state_id : self.find(':selected').val(),
    state_id : $('input[name="state_to[' + country + '][]"]').val(),
    country_id: $('#country_selection').val(),
    action    : 'select_zip_by_state_country'       
  };
});
```

Hope this will help you.